# How to Code this one in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me how to code the dots in the graph below?

[image: Figure]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: You can use TikZ `nodes` for the vertices of the graphs.  Style them as small filled-in circles.  Use TikZ `labels` for the names of the vertices.  Then join them with `\draw` commands.  These keywords and the extensive manual should set you well on your way.

Comment: Are you asking about the dotted line between v_5 and v_n? If so, please show us the code you have so far, even if it doesn't produce your desired output. Always post complete code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{dot/.style=fill, circle, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=-0.1} % node style is a small filled circle

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[var=\p, var=\l, var=\a, count=\n] in {(0:2)/$v_1$/0,(0:1)/$v_2$/-45,(60:1)/$v_3$/60,(120:1)/$v_4$/120,(180:1)/$v_5$/180,(240:1)/$v_n$/270,(300:1)/$v_{n+1}$/330}
    {\node[dot, label=\a:{\l}] (v\n) at \p{};} % \p = location in polar coordinates, \l = label, \a = angle from \p for label
\draw[very thick] (v1)--(v2)--(v3)--(v4)--(v5) (v6)--(v7)--(v2);
\foreach \t in {200,210,220} {\draw[fill] (\t:1) circle[radius=.5pt];} % 3 dots
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```